# Ngrep external machine

Tags: linux, port, ngrep

I have a machine which sends values to port 2712. Locally I use:

```
 ngrep -d lo '' 'port 2712'
```

Which shows me the values:

```
   U 192.168.122.103:51027 -> 192.168.122.103:2712 
     0.5
```

How can I from a machine in the same LAN listen to the same port on the 192.168.122.103 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngrep -d any '' port 2712 and host 192.168.122.103
```

If you know the specific interface (e.g. `eth0`), use that instead of `any`.